# Getting Child Theme's Style.css to Overwrite any Conflicting CSS (WordPress/Masterstudy)

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to get my custom css to take priority over conflicting style properties in the theme.

**What I think I know**
My custom CSS files are loading: If I remove everything else from the "head" section, my custom CSS is implemented.

My custom CSS properties are being overwritten: As the page loads, for just a split-second I see the page with my custom CSS implemented, before it gets overwritten.

Something in the wp_head() function in the "head" tag (this is most of the  section) is causing it: If I remove wp_head() my custom CSS loads (but everything else is broken).

**What I've Tried**
Sample WP_enqueue code I found online
Manually adding my custom CSS file to the end of the "head" section so it loads last
The plugin Real Simple CSS that claims to give your custom CSS priority
The "Additional CSS" feature in Wordpress that is intended to give that custom CSS priority

All of these solutions "work" in that the custom CSS is loaded near/at the very end of the "head" section and should therefore take priority. Despite being the very last CSS loaded, it's still being overwritten.

**The page in question**
https://kingatlaw.attorney/courses/simple-uncontested-divorce-in-north-carolina/

Right now, my custom CSS makes the text on the tabs 100+ pixels large for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a question of "specificity". If I'm understanding this correctly, you're attempting to override a body text style (`body .stm_lms_course__content`) with the `.active` class applied to the parent div containing the body text. Because the theme's own style for `body .stm_lms_course__content` has more specificity, it's being applied over your own addition. In this instance, even applying `!important` won't help you unfortunately. You will have better luck to applying your custom styling to the exact classes set in the original theme. If you're using the Chrome browser, you can see the exact classes applying which styles using the 'Inspect' feature when right-clicking an on-page element.

Unfortunately, a lot of "off-the-shelf" WordPress themes do have some very specific styling which makes it difficult to overwrite (especially if paired with WYSIWYG editors like Elementor or WPBakery)

Comment: I did some research on the specificity concept and made it over-the-top "specific":                        

div.stm-lms-wrapper div.container div.col-md-9 ul.nav.nav-tabs.navtabcustomul li.navtabcustomli a
{
 font-size:112px !important;
}                       Still can't seem to give my 100px font priority. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I got it!!!! The code that worked was as follows: ul.nav, ul.nav-tabs, ul.navtabcustomul li.navtabcustomli a
{
 font-size:24px !important;
}
The trick was using the commas to indicate multiple classes that belong to the same element. Thank you so much Kerri! I have spent at least 8 hours on this and just figured it out in 20 mins after you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Specificity can be a pain, especially when overwriting other people's work with your own modifications! :)